# MSI Setup: Deploy files to different locations

Tags: windows-installer, installation

I'd like to deploy the files in my msi setup which I created with VS 2008 to different location. Some files (especially one) I'd like to move to one dir and the others to the TARGETDIR. 
Best would be if the user can  define InstallPath AND a second Path for (in this case a mdf for MSSQL) other files.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Here is a general approach:

- modify the installation path dialog to support a second path control with its separate Browse button
- use the property associated with this path to create a folder during install and install your files in it

This is not really supported by Visual Studio, but it can easily be done with other setup authoring tools.